# Unable to Reference Nested JSON Object with KnockoutJS

Tags: json, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

I have a JSON string that has a nested JSON object called `data`. I am trying to reference the `status` portion of the nested JSON object, but when I refer to it in my HTML, KnockoutJS does not populate the cells pertaining to Status in my table. KnockoutJS does, however, populate the sender portion of the table.

JSON:

`[{"statusmsg":"OK","data":{"status":"running"},"sender":"hostname","statuscode":0}]`

KnockoutJS (service.js):

```
function ServiceViewModel() {
   var self = this;
   self.rows = ko.observableArray();

   $.ajax({
          method: "GET",
          url: "/mcollective/service/status/servicename",
          success: function(data) {
             var observableData = ko.mapping.fromJSON(data);
             var array = observableData();
             self.rows(array);
          }
       });

};

$(document).ready(function() {
   ko.applyBindings(new ServiceViewModel());
});
```

HTML:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: rows">
              <tr>
                 <td data-bind="text: sender"></td>
                 <td>
                 <span data-bind="text: data.status, 
                                  css: { 'label-success': data.status == 'running', 
                                         'label-danger': data.status == 'stopped',
                                         'label': true }">
                 </span>
                 </td>
                 <td>
              </tr>
</tbody>
```

Note: I am also using Bootstrap for the CSS.

I have checked Firefox web developer console and there are no errors pertaining to my script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mapping plugin turns your properties into observables.

This means that our `data.status` property will be a `ko.observable` which is a function what you need to call without any arguments to get its value.

So you need to fix your `css` binding and write `data.status()` there:

```
<span data-bind="text: data.status, 
                 css: { 'label-success': data.status() == 'running', 
                        'label-danger': data.status() == 'stopped', 
                        'label': true }"></span>
```